# React Question: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am newer to react, and encountering the error in the photo attached when working with the code below:

```
const ProductScreen = ({ history, match }) => {
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(0)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const params = useParams()
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
    const { loading, error, product} = productDetails
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(listProductDetails(params.id))
     }, [dispatch, match])

     const addToCartHandler = () => {
        history.push(`/cart/${params.id}?qty=${qty}`)
     }
```

I believe it has something to do with the history, perhaps being undefined, even though I thought I defined it through the ProductScreen? Any help would be appreciated, as I am stuck. My desired result is when addToCartHandler is used, it takes me to a URL Cart page that includes the QTY in the domain name (Changing later). Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MNU0.png)

Comment: *"I believe it has something to do with the history, perhaps being undefined"* - That is indeed exactly what it happening.  *"even though I thought I defined it through the ProductScreen"* - You **declared** it, but this doesn't guarantee that the variable contains a value.  How is `ProductScreen` being used?  Is a `history` value being passed to it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use navigate instead of history:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

inside function ProductScreen add: 
const navigate = useNavigate();

const addToCartHandler = () => {
   navigate(`/cart/${id}?qty=${qty}`)
}
```